# ImageMagick text watermark on animated gif

Tags: c++, image, imagemagick, gif

```
//add text watermark on animated gif
std::vector<Image> imglist;
std::vector<Drawable> text_list;
text_list.push_back( DrawableText(0, 0, “I love you!"));
text_list.push_back( DrawableStrokeColor(Color("black")));
try {
    readImages(&imglist, "test.gif");
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < imglist.size(); ++i) {
        imglist[i].font("./MILT_RG.ttf");
        imglist[i].draw(text_list);
    }
    writeImages(imglist.begin(), imglist.end(), "test_render.gif");
} catch (Exception &error_) {

    cout << error_.what() << endl;
}
```

But the function **writeImages** cost too much time. In my test example, a gif, 900x600, 20 frames, it takes 1.5 seconds. Is there some solution to speed it up? Or, some better algorithm to add text watermark on gif. Thanks.

Comment: Just guessing wildly till Eric comes online later, but you could maybe try writing your text onto a transparent canvas just once and then compositing that over each of your 20 frames...

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to simplify things by leveraging [STL](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/STL.html)

```cpp
std::vector<Image> imglist;
DrawableList text_list; // <= Same as vector<Drawable>
text_list.push_back( DrawableText(0, 0, "I love you!"));
text_list.push_back( DrawableStrokeColor(Color("black")));
try {
    readImages(&imglist, "test.gif");
    for_each(imglist.begin(), imglist.end(), fontImage("./MILT_RG.ttf"));
    for_each(imglist.begin(), imglist.end(), drawImage(text_list));
    writeImages(imglist.begin(), imglist.end(), "test_render.gif");
} // ...
```

But as your more interested in speed, it might be time to think about parallel-for with [OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers/).

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < imglist.size(); ++i) {
    imglist[i].font("./MILT_RG.ttf");
    imglist[i].draw(text_list);
}
```

Finally, you can move the font into the drawable context, and eliminate the repeat reads of the same TTF file. Probably the best option.

```cpp
std::vector<Image> imglist;
DrawableList text_list;
text_list.push_back( DrawableFont("./MILT_RG.ttf"));
text_list.push_back( DrawableText(32, 32, "I love you!"));
text_list.push_back( DrawableStrokeColor(Color("black")));
try {
    readImages(&imglist, "test.gif");
    for_each(imglist.begin(), imglist.end(), drawImage(text_list));
    writeImages(imglist.begin(), imglist.end(), "test_render.gif");
} // ...
```

YMMV

**Edit**

As Mark pointed out in the comments, drawing the text in a temporary image once & compositing across all frames might be faster.

```cpp
Geometry imgSize = imglist[0].size();
Image imgText(imgSize, Color("transparent"));
imgText.draw(text_list);
for_each(imglist.begin(), imglist.end(), compositeImage(imgText, 0, 0, AtopCompositeOp));
```

Comment: In my test, the loop for drawing text costs a little more than 100ms, while the writeImages operation costs more than 1300ms. the bottleneck is  probably the writeImages. Do you have any idea of the reason, please?

Comment: @Yang You could maybe try writing on a `tmpfs` or RAMdrive filesystem to see if it is a slow disk causing your problems. Another possibility is that IM is maybe trying to optimise your palette across all 20 frames...

Comment: @emcconville A slow disk was not the trouble, because I tried to write images in a blob and it's slow too. Your latter guess might be right. Is there any way to verify it and do some optimizations?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible way. We can parallelize the program according to above answer from @emcconville. But we must parallelize the cost operation, which is quantize. Here is the code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < imglist.size(); ++i) {
imglist[i].font("./MILT_RG.ttf");
imglist[i].draw(text_list);
imglist[i].quantize(false);
}
```